# Почему перестает работать font awesome?

Tags: css, fontawesome

Есть

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Перестаёт работать когда помещаю в ссылку с классом

```
<a href="#" class="m-menu-link">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

Есть два стиля для больших экранов и меньше 990 пикселей.В главном стиле

```
.m-menu-link {
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:3rem;
}
```

а в стиле для медия запросов

```
@media(max-width: 991px){
     html{
        font-size: 7px;

     }

     .visible-lg{
        display: none;
     }
     .m-menu-link {
        display:block;

     }
}
```

Причем если удалить класс  из ссылки всё работает.Так же перестали работать иконки соцсетей вчера всё отображалось прекрасно а сегодня ромбики.

UPD: У меня это всё подключалось с локальных файлов.Вставил ссылку с cdna заработало до этого без импортанта через cdn не хотело.Сейчас попробую ещё для ссылок на соцсети прописать.Спасибо.

Comment: На оф. сайте нет значка с таким классом [Оф сайт fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=bars)

Comment: Думаю автор  воспользовался [этим ресурсом устаревшим](https://fontawesome.ru/icon/bars/)

Comment: работает как и fa fa-bars так fas fa-bars дело в том , что оба варианта перестают работать когда я помещаю их в ссылку с классом

Comment: Нет я юзал этот сайт https://fontawesome.com/start

Comment: Ну тогда остается одно... Ты где-то изменил `font-weight` && `font-family`

Comment: Но почему тогда просто так работает а в ссылке с классом нет?

Comment: Ссылке какие-нибудь стили связанные со шрифтом не прописаны?

Comment: С гугл фонтс есть ссылка.<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro" rel="stylesheet">.Но дело в том , что иконка просто так же работает а в ссылке с классом нет.UPD:Удалял шрифт проьблему не решило

Comment: У меня это всё подключалось с локальных файлов.Вставил ссылку с cdna заработало до этого без импортанта через cdn не хотело.Сейчас попробую ещё для ссылок на соцсети прописать.Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В медиа попробуй добавить `important`.

Вот так например:

```
 .m-menu-link {
    display:block!important;
 }
```

Если не получиться, тогда класс для `<i>`:

```
 .m-menu-link i {
    display: block;
 }
```

Думаю, второй вариант поможет. Если нет, тогда ссылку в студию чтобы изучать.

Comment: После iportant стал выводиться квадратик .Пробывал так же через important тегу html задавать шрифт Font Awesome 5

Comment: Оставьте ссылку на ресурс.

Answer (score -1):

У меня это всё подключалось с локальных файлов. Вставил ссылку с cdn заработало до этого без импорта через cdn не хотело. Сейчас попробую ещё для ссылок на соцсети прописать..